# Function for an event

Tags: javascript, function, events, dom-events

I would like to create a function from this:

```
element.onclick = function(e){
    ... code ...
}
```

To something like this:

```
element.onclick  = doSomething(e);
element2.onclick = doSomething(e);

function doSomething(e){
    ... code ...
}
```

In this way I could call the function multiple times but in this way `e` is not passed as an event so doesn't works.

How should I do this?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you trying to make this onclick function a variable and call it multiple times? Or would you just like to run whatever's in that function anywhere?

Comment: Sry I'm confused too, I edited my question :P

Comment: Hey the problem was with (e) in `element.onclick  = doSomething(e);` lol :D It works now thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but you can declare a function and use it as the handler for multiple elements. The `event` argument will still be passed.

```
element.onclick = someHandler;
anotherElem.onclick = someHandler;
yetAnotherElem.onclick = someHandler;

function someHandler(e){
    e = e || event;
    ... code ...
}
```

Each of the 3 elements will call the same handler, and have the event object as its argument.

---

**EDIT:** With regard to your edit, you were *calling* the function and assigning its return value to `onclick` instead of assigning the function itself.

Seems from your comment that you figured that out though. :o)

Answer (score 1):

```
function onClickHandler(e){
    //Do stuff...
}

element.onclick = onClickHandler;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to create a normal function and use it in various ways?

```
function fnName(e) {
  ... code ...
}
```

Can be used in various ways:

```
element.onclick = fnName;

fnName();

//Call it however you like?
```

Answer (score 1):

First you gotta give your function a name.

```
function clickEvent(e) {
    ... do stuff ...
}
```

Then attach it onto the element like this:

```
element.onClick = clickEvent;
```

When the event is triggered, the event will automatically get passed into the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it in the form of:

```
function fnName(e){
    ... code ...
}
```

and then you can call fnName and pass the variable you need.

If your function does not really need the 'e', you can write

```
function fnName(){
    ...code...
}
```

Comment: You can then say `element.onclick = fnName` and it will work as the first example code in the question does.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this:

element.onclick = function(e){

```
myfunc();
```

}

function myfunc()

{

... code

}